# Как отредактировать автозагрузчик Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, автозагрузка

Устанавливал на ноутбук Windows XP второй операционной системой в дополнение к Windows 7 Когда надобность отпала - удалил, вместе с логическим разделом диска. Однако в списке загружаемых операционных систем осталась запись Windows XP и при включении компьютера на секунду появляется вопрос о выборе операционной системы, после этого Windows 7 нормально загружается и работает. Как избавиться от этого самого секундного появления вариантов выбора операционной системы? Глаза мозолит

Comment: Закрыть глаза на секунду

Comment: Это выполняется с помощью `BCDEDIT` - `редактора данных конфигурации загрузки`. Adding, editing and removing boot menu entries https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries#removing-a-boot-entry-in-windows-vista-and-later

Answer (score 1):

Нажмите "WIN+R", наберите msconfig, нажмите ENTER. Выберите закладку "загрузка" и удалите строку где указано Windows XP. Должно помочь

Comment: В msconfig указана только Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Свойства компьютера -> вкладка "Дополнительно" -> Параметры : и там можно выбрать что загружать по дефолту и/или вовсе убрать выбор загрузки.

Comment: Указано две операционные системы, но как удалить строчку с XP не ясно. Галочка с пункта отображать список операционных систем снята, но всё равно окно выбора при загрузке на мгновение появляется

Answer (score 0):

Тогда попробуйте так. Панель управления\Система и безопасность\Система\Дополнительные параметры системы\Дополнительно\Загрузка и восстановление\Параметры и убрать галочку "Отображать список операционных систем"

Comment: Не надо плодить вопросы. Воспользуйтесь кнопкой ["Править"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/615137/edit), чтобы дополнить свой ответ.